# nextjs14 : "onSubmit" mode in react-hook-form doesn't trigger when using actions

Tags: next.js, react-hook-form, zod, server-action

Trying to implement Zod validation on **both Client and server side**, when using forms in NextJs14 and server actions.
When setting mode to `onSubmit` (which is the default mode) in the RHF `useForm` hook, the client side validation is not triggered when pressing the submit button. Directly goes to the server side validation (that works).
However, when changing the mode to `onChange` or `onBlur`, the validation is working fine.
It's worth to mention that the **isValid** boolean, also provided by the `useForm` hooks is `False` before submitting which means that Zod is doing is Job. But the errors objects is empty, so can not displayed the pb to the users.
Does anyone got the same issue ?

```
"use client";

import { zodResolver } from "@hookform/resolvers/zod";
import { FC, useEffect } from "react";
import { useFormState, useFormStatus } from "react-dom";
import {
  FieldErrors,
  FieldPath,
  UseFormRegister,
  useForm,
} from "react-hook-form";
import InputField from "./InputField/InputField";
import { TestFormState, getFullName } from "./testAction";
import { TTestForm, formSchema } from "./validationTestForm";

type ITestFormProps = {};

export type FormValues = TTestForm;

export function FormContent({
  register,
  isValid,
  errors,
}: {
  register: UseFormRegister<FormValues>;
  isValid: boolean;
  errors: FieldErrors<FormValues>;
}) {
  const { pending } = useFormStatus();

  return (
    <>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start">
        <input {...register("firstName")} placeholder="First name" />
      </div>
      <div className="flex items-center justify-start">
        <input {...register("lastName")} placeholder="Last name" />
      </div>
      <button type="submit" disabled={pending}>
        Send
      </button>
      <div>{pending && <span>Loading...</span>}</div>
      <div>{`${errors} - ${isValid}`}</div>
    </>
  );
}

const TestForm: FC<ITestFormProps> = (_props: ITestFormProps): JSX.Element => {
  const {
    register,
    formState: { isValid, errors },
    setError,
    reset,
  } = useForm<FormValues>({
    resolver: zodResolver(formSchema),
    criteriaMode: "all",
    mode:"onSubmit" // <-- "isValid" is correct but not "errors". Changing to onBlur fix the issue
  });
  const [state, formAction] = useFormState<TestFormState, FormData>(
    getFullName,
    null
  );
  return (
    <>
      <form action={formAction}>
        <FormContent register={register} isValid={isValid} errors={errors} />
      </form>
      <>{state && JSON.stringify(state)}</>
    </>
  );
};

export default TestForm;
export type { ITestFormProps };
```

**schema**

```
export const formSchema = zfd.formData({
  firstName: zfd.text(z.string().min(2, "Too short").max(20, "Too long")),
  lastName: zfd.text(
    z.string().min(2, "Too short").max(20, "Too long").optional()
  )
});

export type TTestForm = z.infer<typeof formSchema>;
```

Comment: noone can help me? Fighting for several days now